# Can't Access React Reducer Value from Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-reducer

In the code below, a keypress event detector is implemented through `useEffect` which attempts to update `index` through the `useReducer` function. However, the `console.log` output doesn't seem to show that the update works even though the `button` component's value updates.

On the other hand, when the button is clicked, the `index` variable seems to update as indicated by the `console.log` and the content of the `button` also updates as expected.

Why is there such a disparity and - if I needed to access the updated `index` variable after a keypress, how could I go about doing it?

The code is below:

```js
const { useEffect, useReducer } = React;

const indexReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action === "decrease") {
    return state-1
  } else if (action === "increase") {
    return state+1
  } else if (action === "reset") {
    return 0
  }
}

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useReducer(indexReducer, 0)
  const incrementCounter = () => {
    console.log(counter)
    setCounter("increase")
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", incrementCounter, false);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", incrementCounter, false);
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={incrementCounter}>{"COUNT: " + counter}</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`incrementCounter` is redefined on every render, and has a closure around the value of `counter` at the time it is defined. In the `keydown` handler's case, this is `0` (since your effect only runs once). Notice that the the `onClick` version is also always `n-1` behind the `button` text.

You can move your logging into your reducer:

```js
const { useEffect, useReducer } = React;

const indexReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action === "decrease") {
    return state-1
  } else if (action === "increase") {
    console.log(state+1)
    return state+1
  } else if (action === "reset") {
    return 0
  }
}

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useReducer(indexReducer, 0)
  const incrementCounter = () => {
    setCounter("increase")
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", incrementCounter, false);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", incrementCounter, false);
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={incrementCounter}>{"COUNT: " + counter}</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Or use a functional `setState`:

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
  const incrementCounter = () => {
    setCounter(counter => {
      console.log(counter + 1)
      return counter + 1         
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", incrementCounter, false);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", incrementCounter, false);
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={incrementCounter}>{"COUNT: " + counter}</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I see what you mean. Would you be able to suggest a method in which I can still use keypresses but have the updated `counter`

Comment: You could log in your reducer instead of your handler, or use the functional version of useState to store the counter and log there.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really new to react. Could you please provide an example? I'm not quite sure what you mean

Comment: No need to apologize. I've edited my answer.